# Android - checkbox dropdown menu

Tags: android, json, eclipse, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I would like to make a checkbox dropdown menu as shown on a picture in the link below:
http://postimg.org/image/49xpymtuf/
Problem is I couldn’t find any examples of such kind only when there is a dropdown list than checkboxes.  I would really like to make the category item as a checkbox to select all the subcategories (checkboxes beneath).
I appreciate any help :)

Comment: That is not a drop-down menu. It is not even from Android, but rather from Windows.

Comment: Instead you can try [multiselection spinner](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=spinner+with+multiple+selections+android&oq=spinner&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j69i59j0l3.5217j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&psj=1&q=multi+select+spinner+in+android)

Comment: I know that, im just wondering is it posible to make in Android something like that.

Comment: I think spinner is not a good idea. Look at ExpandableListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ExpandableListView. [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)